# Calculating the electrical potential of a disk with variable surface charge?

Tags: electric-fields, potential

I have a problem that is stumping me (mostly because of the integrals I'm guessing).  We have a disk (of radius $a$) in the $xy$ plane with charge $\rho_s=\rho_0\cdot(1+\sin(\phi))$ and I have to find what the electric potential on the $z$-axis is. The integral I have set up looks like this:

$$V = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\cdot \Bigg[\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{\rho_0\cdot(1+\sin(\phi'))\rho'd\rho'd\phi'}{(z^2+\phi'^2)^\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg]$$

I think this part is correct, but then I have to end up integrating

$$\frac{\sin(\phi')}{(z^2+\phi'^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$$
and as far as I can tell there aren't any elementary operations to solve this...

Would anyone mind sharing some insight for this problem?

Regards.

Comment: There is  a typo (or mistake?) in the denominator, right?  Once you fix that, I think it should be do-able.

Comment: I have tried... with limited success.  I am also wondering  if my denominator looks correct, or if it should be $(z^2+\phi'^2+\rho'^2)^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: That new denominator also can't possibly be correct.  Check the units...

Comment: an angle and a length do not have the same units - this should make you doubtful of your expression. By the way, is the disk of finite extent?

Comment: @garyp damn, you beat me to it :<

Comment: Sorry - made an edit.  The disk is of radius $a$. And that makes sense that I can't have a $\phi$ there. Didn't think about it. Should that $\phi$ turn into  a $\rho'\phi'$?

Comment: draw it down, find the right triangle whose one leg is formed by $z$ and find the correct expression - I'm sure you'll find it :)

Comment: Yeah... I'm just not getting this one...

Comment: Ask yourself:  Does the distance from the source point to the field point depend on $\phi'$?

Comment: No - I think the distance is $|z-\rho|$ after doing some reflection.